YML to C# Classes Converter Issues
I have a YML file provided by a contactor and have converted it to C# classes using the Unchase Extension for VS2022. It works but am having difficulty with some conversion parameters.
The YML sample:
TripRef:
  type: object
  additionalProperties: false
  required:
    - versionId
  properties:
    versionId:
      type: string
      format: uuid
    legNumber:
      type: integer
      format: int32

There seems to be only one option for required json properties. The option ON seems to give me the correct json properties for versionId but legNumber just doesn't make sense. My test shows that the raw data has this "legNumber": null and it bombs when trying to deserialize the object.
I am at a loss on how to proceed. I've looked through the options and I cant seem to find any that would properly convert those YML fields that have no explicit [Required] or [NullValueHandling] settings. Any guidance appreciated.
Option: OFF
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "13.19.0.0 (NJsonSchema v10.9.0.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v13.0.3.0))")]
public partial class TripRef
{
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("versionId", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    public System.Guid VersionId { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("legNumber", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public int legNumber { get; set; }
}

Option: ON
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "13.19.0.0 (NJsonSchema v10.9.0.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v13.0.3.0))")]
public partial class TripRef
{
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("versionId", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Always)]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    public System.Guid VersionId { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("legNumber", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public int legNumber { get; set; }
}

